# How do we create this linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given a function over positive integers:

$f(N)=N-8K$

For any $N$ we can choose an appropriate $K$ such that output is always b/w 0 to 7. Now how do we convert this function into a linear system of equations such that for a variable $d$:

1. $d$ is equal to 1 iff $f(n)$ 2 or 3
2. $d$ is equal to 0 iff $f(n)$ is anything else (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7).
3. We are allowed to introduce new variables that have an implicit
   limit on the values they can acquire (i.e. some var $x$ can have only some implicit predetermined values).
4. The number of new equations introduced must be greater than the
   number of new variables introduced.

Comment: can someone please help with this??

Comment: can someone help with this??